# Access "th" in Listview

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to access the "th", in the code behind. I would like to add padding to the header depending on the item value.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" >
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="UserLayoutTbl">
                        <tr runat="server" style="">
                            <th runat="server" width="140" align="left">
                                Date</th>
                            <th runat="server" width="140" align="left">
                                Ref. No.</th>
                            <th runat="server" width="270" align="left">
                                Description</th>
                           <%-- <th runat="server" width="90" align="right" style = '<%# GetAmountLabelStyle() %>'>
                                Amount</th>--%>
                                <th id="Th1" runat="server" width="90" align="right">
                                Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give an ID to the  element you want to change. After DataBind of the ListView, you can access the control by its ID using the FindControl method of the ListView. Then, you can convert the returned control to HtmlTableCell to proper handle it:

```
// thDate is the <th> ID
HtmlTableCell thDate = lstItems.FindControl("thDate") as HtmlTableCell;
```