# How to keep styling on ListView Tableheader Link (after programmatically setting value)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asplinkbutton, tableheader

I would like to change the text on a particular table header in a Layout Template in a ListView programmatically (depending on the value in the database). It works but the styling is no longer using the LinkButton styling(green and clickable). Instead it's black and bold (not clickable)

I used the following ([Access "th" in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385325/access-th-in-listview)):

My c#:

```
HtmlTableCell thCustCol = lstAuthorizations.FindControl("customColumn") as HtmlTableCell;
thCustCol.InnerText = query.Select(x => x.Custom1).First().ToString();
```

I also tried applying FindControl to "LinkButton10" instead, but then it had an (null reference)exception.

My aspx:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                      <th runat="server" id="customColumn"><asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton10" runat="server" CommandArgument="Custom1" CommandName="Sort">Group ID</asp:LinkButton></th>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Table Headers]

The "1000" is a tableheader, but should be a green LinkButton like "Member Name"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value to the ID of the LinkButton, I needed to associate the LinkButton to the th in the c# code and then set the value:

```
LinkButton lk = thCustCol.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
lk.Text = "link text";
```